# How can I get this css to display correctly in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I have the following simple code:

```
<div style="float:right">
   <h2>Header <div style="float:right;background-color:red">my text</div></h2>
   More text
</div>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CeZ9G/)

This displays the way I want it to in Firefox and IE - with the "my text" showing up to the right of "Header" on the same line. However, in Chrome, the "my text" gets pushed down a line, next to "more text".

I know that I can get this to work by moving the "my text" div before the "header" text:

```
<h2><div style="float:right;background-color:red">my text</div>Header</h2>
```

But for other reasons, I need to keep the html the way it is and would like to accomplish this using css if possible. Is there any way to get this to display the way I want it in Chrome (just by changing the css)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<div style="float:right">
<h2>Header <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:red">My text</div></h2>
More text
</div>
```

This shows exactly you want [See This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/YDf3Q/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code is helpfull to you...

```
    <div style="float:right;width:170px">
     <h2>Header <div style="float:right;background-color:red">my text</div></h2>
     More text
    </div>
```

And the following code is also helpfull.....

```
 <div style="float:right">
  <h2>Header <div style="display:inline;background-color:red">My text</div></h2>
  More text
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the `float:right` and replace with `display:inline;`

Image Below

[image]